# Azure DevOps release is skipping the publishing step

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to deploy a Java EE application on Azure web apps with the MySql database hosted on azure web apps itself through an Azure DevOps repository. The pipeline builds successfully when I try to release the same pipeline, the release downloads the artifact, deploys it on the web apps server but skips the publishing artifact step. I don't know if that should make a difference but when I check the URL, the application has been deployed on, the apache server says 404 not found.

I was trying to do the exact same thing few days back, my release then,  had the Publish artifact step but it was failing at that step saying publish path not found

Comment: Share your pipeline. It sounds like you're using the wrong task; publish artifacts is for builds, not releases.

Comment: what you want to achieve by using publish artifacts task in release. This task is normally used in build to publish the artifacts from build to release in order to be deployed.